# Why is PHP Session variable changing to something unrelated when retrieved in an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a page at `example.com/add-results.php` with a large form where one of the "fields" is this area below where people can upload an image. Standard behavior with a "Choose Image" button, then when you choose it, an "Upload" button appears.  Then you click that and a preview of the now-uploaded-the-server image appears with a "Remove/Change" button.

Important note here how the default `src` for the preview image is "no-image.png" (this comes into play later)...

```
<label class="caption" for="">Pool Image </label> (OPTIONAL - You can add one later if you don't have one now)<br>                
    <span>for testing: <?php echo $_SESSION['poolid'];?></span>
    <div id="preview"><img id="image" src="no-image.png" /></div>
    <label for="uploadImage" id="custom-file-upload">
        Choose Image
    </label>
    <span id="file-selected"></span>
    <input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" />
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Upload" class="displaynone webkit">
    <input id="remove-image" class="displaynone" type="button" value="Remove/Change">
    <div id="err"></div>
```

Also included on the `add-results.php` page is this javascript file which makes an AJAX call...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:file").change(function (){
      $( "#button" ).show();
     });

 $('#uploadImage').bind('change', function() { var fileName = ''; fileName = $(this).val(); $('#file-selected').html(fileName); });

 $("#button").click(function(){
    var imageData = new FormData();
    imageData.append('image', $('#uploadImage')[0].files[0]);

    //Make ajax call here:
    $.ajax({
          url: "/upload-image-results-ajax.php",
          type: 'POST',
          processData: false, // important
          contentType: false, // important
          data: imageData,
          beforeSend : function()  {
            $("#err").fadeOut();
           },
       success: function(result) {
            if(result=='invalid file') {
             // invalid file format.
             $("#err").html("Invalid File !").fadeIn();
            } else {

             // view uploaded file.
             $("#image").attr('src', '/'+result);
            /* $("#preview").html(data).fadeIn();*/
            /* $("#form")[0].reset(); */
             //show the remove image button
             $('#file-selected').empty();
             $( "#remove-image" ).show();
             $( "#custom-file-upload" ).hide();
             $( "#uploadImage" ).hide();
             $( "#button" ).hide();
            }
          },
         error: function(result)  {
              $("#err").html("errorcity").fadeIn();
          }      
     });
   });

  $("#remove-image").click(function(){
    //Make ajax call here:
    $.ajax({
          url: "/remove-image-results.php",
          type: 'POST',
          processData: false, // important
          contentType: false, // important
       success: function(result) {
            if(result=='gone') {
             $("#image").attr('src', '/images/no-image.png');
             $('#file-selected').empty();
             $( "#custom-file-upload" ).show();
             $( "#remove-image" ).hide();
             $( "#uploadImage" ).hide();
             $( "#button" ).hide();
            } else {
            }
          },
         error: function(result)  {
              $("#err").html("error").fadeIn();
          }      
     });
   });

 //deleting uploaded image (if one exists) if user cancel's out of Add Results screen
 $("#cancel-and-remove-image").click(function(){
    //Make ajax call here:
    $.ajax({
          url: "/remove-image-results.php",
          type: 'POST',
          processData: false, // important
          contentType: false, // important
          success: function(result) {
          },
          error: function(result)  {

          }      
     });
   });

  });
```

Finally, this is a page called `upload-image-results-ajax.php` which performs the actual upload task called by the AJAX call above...

```
<?php
require_once("includes/session.php");
$poolid=$_SESSION['poolid']; //lowercase it first so we get exact matches
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    $img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    // get uploaded file's extension
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    //checking if image exists for this pool and removing if so, before adding new image in its place
    if(file_exists("uploads/results/".$poolid.".png")) {
     unlink("uploads/results/".$poolid.".png");
    }

    // checks valid format
    if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions))  { 
    //re-size the image and make it a PNG before sending to server
    $final_image = $poolid . ".png";
    $path = "uploads/results/".strtolower($final_image); 
    $size = getimagesize($tmp);
    $ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; // width/height
    if( $ratio > 1) {
        $width = 200;
        $height = 200/$ratio;
    }
    else {
        $width = 200*$ratio;
        $height = 200;
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($tmp));
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
    imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$size[0],$size[1]);
    imagedestroy($src);
    imagepng($dst, $path); // adjust format as needed
    imagedestroy($dst);

    echo $path ."?".rand(1,32000); 
    } else {
      echo 'invalid file';
    }
}
?>
```

Note how it says "$poolid=$_SESSION['poolid'];".  That's the key to all this.  This session ID definitely is set on the add-results.php page with an actual poolid, like p0902ftel7

QUICK ASIDE:  Since I know someone would ask, let's get this out of the way. A session definitely IS started at the top of add-results.php and also at the top of the page above using an include of `session.php`, which contains simply:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

The final image location/url should be in the format of "example.com/uploads/results/(poolid).png"

So an example using an actual poolid would be:  "example.com/uploads/results/p0902ftel7.png"

So as long as $_SESSION['poolid'] is set (which again it is), the poolid will be set and the URL of the image will correct.

Now, when I upload an image, it does upload the image to the server, but instead of being named "p0902fte17.png", it is named "no-image.png".  So the full URL of the uploaded image is something like:  `example.com/uploads/results/no-image.png.png?22555`

FYI, the "?22555" is just a random number being added to help with cached images issues when the image is previewed.

I am completely baffled by this behavior and am praying someone knows what might be happening. I've lost about 8 hours looking into this now.  I can't fathom how the value of $_SESSION['poolid'] changes from an actual id (like p0902fte17) to "no-image.png" (the default image `src` from `add-results.php`).

Any ideas?

Comment: *"Now, when I upload an image, it does upload the image to the server,"* - How are you uploading it? I don't see `move_uploaded_file` anywhere.

Comment: anything from error reporting and the developer console? and a var_dump()

Comment: Nope, console is clean.  And I am not familiar with move_uploaded_file, but I promise you, the image IS getting uploaded to my server (by imagepng, which should be enough right?)

Comment: `.bind()` in jquery was superseded by .on() years ago, and deprecated more recently. you should be using .on() for new code. http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Anyway, can you post the content of session.php as well? It might be important, since we're trying to fix a problem with the session

Comment: @ADyson, I added session.php contents (sorry bout that) and also changed `bind()` to `on()`, thanks for the heads up there.  Still behaving the same, so if you have other ideas, please let me know.